# How to stop keydown event being stuck?

Tags: javascript, events, keydown, dom-events, onkeydown

I expect the behavior of the program listed below to be like this:

1. I click on the input.
2. I press enter.
3. The line "Press Enter once again" appears.
4. I go out of input by clicking somewhere on the page.
5. I press Enter.
6. Then the line "You have pressed Enter 2 times" appears.

The real behavior of this program:

1. I click on the input.
2. I press enter.
3. The lines "Press Enter once again" and "You have pressed Enter 2 times" appear.

I have 2 questions:

1) What is the reason for that? I have pressed Enter only once.
2) How to make this program behave the way I expect it to behave?

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.value = "Click on this field and press Enter";
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        let div2 = document.createElement("div");
        div2.innerHTML = "Press Enter once again";
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                let div3 = document.createElement("div");
                div3.innerHTML = "You have pressed Enter 2 times";
                document.body.appendChild(div3);
            }
        });
        document.body.appendChild(div2);    
    }
});
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: You are attaching the event listener twice. Use `.preventDefault()`?

Comment: This event listener is added to different elements. .preventDefault() did not help.

Comment: Also, you have attached the event listener to `document` instead of the field. As the event bubbles, the `document` event listener executes.

Comment: That was done on purpose. The first Enter should be pressed on the field, and the second one can be pressed anywhere

Comment: Ahhh. Okay. Use `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: I have added an answer with that in mind; check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down. What is happening is that your if condition is immediately checking if the key was pressed, and it has been so `e.keyCode` is always `13`.

The easiest method to solve this is with the following bit of code:

```
let input = document.createElement("input");
let isPressed = false;
input.value = "Click on this field and press Enter";
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && isPressed) {
    let div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.innerHTML = "You have pressed Enter 2 times";
    document.body.appendChild(div3);
  }
});
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    event.stopPropagation()
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        if ( isPressed ) {
          return;
        } else {
          let div2 = document.createElement("div");
          div2.innerHTML = "Press Enter once again";
          isPressed = true;
          document.body.appendChild(div2); 
        }   
    }
});
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

You can try that out [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbLpLY). You can refractor this to your liking. :)

Keeping your original code in mind, [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYLOaj) is the updated version.

---

To understand how this bit works, it's simple: when there is an event in element `a` and the wrapper for that element is `b`, the event travels up through a process known as event bubbling (because bubbles *rise up*).

Due to that, the second event listener, on the `document`, gets executed.

To stop that from happening, you can use `.stopPropagation()` on the `event` object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! It works. But I still do not understand the process. In my initial code the second event is added only after the Enter key is pressed. Why then it is activated? I pressed Enter key once, not twice.

Comment: When you press it once, an event is created; this event is caught by your `input`'s `eventListener`. However, the event is still not dead; imagine that you haven't called `return` on a function. This event then travels up your DOM tree where it is caught by the `document`'s event listener and it executes it twice.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things going on here. You were attaching the listener twice, the second time on the whole document, this event then got triggered instantly when the event bubbled. You didn't need to use two different elements for the message either, if you keep track of if enter was pressed. You should also use `textContent` over `innerHTML` for security reasons :)

Here is the code rewritten

```
let enterHasBeenPressed = false;

let input = document.createElement("input");
input.value = "Click on this field and press Enter";
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        onEnterPressed();
    }
});
document.body.appendChild(input);

let text = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(text);

function onEnterPressed() {
    if (!enterHasBeenPressed) {
        text.textContent = "Press Enter once again";
        enterHasBeenPressed = true;
        return;
    }

    text.textContent = "You have pressed Enter 2 times";
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbjojR